# IONIC - Create a custom keyboard instead use a plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, custom-keyboard

i'm having trouble to build a custom keyboard using ionic framework.
I'm just started use this framework, so all information will be very helpful.

I have tried to use their plugin from [driftyco](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard)
They didn't provide clear tutorial of how to use it, so it is really difficult to implement.

Then i found this tutorial from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nsa7BuoWhU)
But it is for android studio. I need some guide like this to build in Ionic, 
can someone please help me?

Comment: Ionic keyboard plugin does not provide support for creating custom keyboards.

Comment: thank you for your respon. Is it mean imposible to build a custom keyboard using ionic? @Emre

Comment: Not that I know of...

Comment: did you get any solution for this? @lloistborn

Comment: I got the same question here, did you find a way to do it finally with Ionic? I'm really considering it is not possible "yet" to create a custom keyboard using Ionic framework. So we gotta have to go through the native path with Swift and Java for iOS and Android.